# Unable to resolve class java.nio.file.FileSystems

Tags: java, grails, java-7

Mac OS x 10.7

[me@air]> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home


export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7"
```

[me@air]> which java

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

I want to use Java 1.7 NIO in one of the services and i got the following:

```
grails> run-app 
...
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
/path/to/Acquiring.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class java.nio.file.FileSystems
 @ line 7, column 1.
   import java.nio.file.FileSystems
   ^
/path/to/Acquiring.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class java.nio.file.Path
 @ line 8, column 1.
   import java.nio.file.Path
   ^
2 errors
| Error Error running script run-app : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

What a hell!?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is if you run echo $JAVA_HOME, it is set to an older version of Java.  Some tools like Maven (and I think Grails) use JAVA_HOME and not just the path.

Comment: $JAVA_HOME was set in advance `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7"`